# Clean and idiomatic string join in Rails view helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

Please note this is not a question asking for any working solution, but a question of a *what is the best practice?* kind.

Throughout my views I have a lot of occurrences of the code like this (I use HAML):

```
= t("some.key")
%b= t("other.key.#{string}")
%i= string
```

As soon as it is used in many different places I decided to extract it to a helper. But I realized that I do not understand what is the cleanest way to do it.

I can think of using string concatenation (`+`), or string formatting (`"%s %s %s" % [...]`), or array join (`[...].join("\n")`) but all of these methods look a bit excessive for me, because I have to build some other objects (strings, arrays) or specify delimiters(`" "` or `"\n"`) and bothering with `html_safe` instead of just declaring three string.

I thought that `concat` is what is supposed to work this way

```
def long_string(string)
  concat t("some.key")
  concat content_tag(:b, t("other.key.#{string}"))
  concat content_tag(:i, t(string)
end
```

... and it works, but it forces me to *execute* the helper instead of *evaluating* it, which is not idiomatic, I mean to use

```
%p- long_string(string)
```

instead of

```
%p= long_string(string)
```

Of course I can extract it to a partial, but it seems to much for a code of three lines.

That said, am I missing some clean and elegant way to concatenate three HTML-enriched lines in a helper, or `concat`/partial/dirty array joins are my only options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a lot of HTML I would definitely go for extracting the partial. Nothing writes and reads HTML cleaner than HAML in my personal opinion.

If it is a bunch of string interpolation, composing a lot of values, I sometimes use helpers to clean up my view, but they would always return strings, I *never* use `concat` in my helpers, this makes my helpers better testable as well (just check if the string result is what I expect it to be).

So, for your example it would be

```
def long_string(str)
  result = []
  result << t("some.key")
  result << content_tag(:b, t("other.key.#{string}"))
  result << content_tag(:i, string)
  result.join(" ").html_safe
end
```

and in your view you can just write

```
%p= long_string('whatevvva')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I used to have lots of `.join(" ").html_safe` in my code :) But now trying to keep away from this style. Now I tend to agree that partial is the proper way to do this.